# property not being recognized in view controller

Tags: iphone

I have custom `NSObject` with an `NSNumber` property.  I'm trying to set and recall this property in a view controller that includes the custom object's header.  However, the view controller doesn't recognize the property as "something in a structure or union".  I've treated this `NSNumber` property exactly like an `NSString` property in the same custom object.  I don't get these sorts of errors with the string.

Here's the custom object's header:

```
@interface IndividualsTab : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *itemList;
    NSString *personsName;
    NSNumber *customTip;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *itemList;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *personsName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *customTip;
```

Here's a sample of usage in the view controller:

```
IndividualsTab *thisTab = [self.listOfPeople objectAtIndex:(tipBeingEdited - 20)];
thisTab.customTip = tipRate;
```

That last line gives me an error.  However, a similar call for `thisTab.personsName` works properly.  I was sure to put a default value for both properties in the custom class's init code.

Any ideas?

Comment: No idea. What's the error? Where's `listOfPeople` coming from? What is the type of `tipRate`? Is it a pointer to an `NSNumber`?

Comment: Are you sure thisTab isn't nil?

Comment: listOfPeople is an NSMutableArray filled with instances of IndividualsTab.  Yes, tipRate is a pointer to an NSNumber.  thisTab shouldn't be nil, but if it were, that would be a run-time error, not a compile error (which is what I'm getting), correct?  The error I'm getting is "request for member 'customTip' in something not a structure or union." Thanks for helping narrow the scope, anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to @synthesize your properties?

Comment: Yes I have. Right after the @implementation.